# how get the max of sum in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

i want to return the maximum value of  Sum(units_sold) in this code

```
SELECT dim_product.product_name, Sum(fact_sales.units_sold) AS 
SumOfunits_sold
FROM dim_product 
INNER JOIN fact_sales 
ON dim_product.product_code = fact_sales.product_code
GROUP BY dim_product.product_name
ORDER BY Sum(fact_sales.units_sold) DESC;
```

but i can't do this i try to use limit by this way

```
SELECT dim_product.product_name, Sum(fact_sales.units_sold) AS 
    SumOfunits_sold
    FROM dim_product 
    INNER JOIN fact_sales 
    ON dim_product.product_code = fact_sales.product_code
    GROUP BY dim_product.product_name
    ORDER BY Sum(fact_sales.units_sold) DESC limit 1;
```

but it is nit work for me...

Comment: try order by SumOfunits_sold desc limit 1;

Comment: i do that but it doesn't work to me , just a question can i use limit in MS access ?

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: i use Microsoft access , i did that by add (TOP 1) , but can i get the first and last record at the same time? i want to get maximum and minimum of Sum(fact_sales.units_sold) how can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you state:

> I want to return the maximum value of `Sum(units_sold)` in this code...

If you merely want the maximum and/or minimum value of the sum across all groups, you could alternatively use a subquery such as the following example demonstrates:

```
select min(q.s) as minsold, max(q.s) as maxsold from
(
    select d.product_name, sum(f.units_sold) as s
    from dim_product d inner join fact_sales f on d.product_code = f.product_code
    group by d.product_name
) q
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help , its work for me correctly , thank u sir for this help

Comment: but i have a question how can i select the product name with this code?  i want in a result show me the product_name for the maximum value and minimum value   how can i do that from your code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you intended to use `TOP` here:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dp.product_name, SUM(fs.units_sold) AS SumOfunits_sold
FROM dim_product dp
INNER JOIN fact_sales fs
    ON dp.product_code = fs.product_code
GROUP BY
    dp.product_name
ORDER BY
    SUM(fe.units_sold) DESC;
```

`LIMIT` is not part of the ANSI SQL standard, though it is supported by a few databases, such as MySQL, SQLite, and Postgres.

If you also wanted to return the recorr having the smallest sum, then one easy way would be to take a union with another query finding that minimum:

```
-- query from above
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 dp.product_name, SUM(fs.units_sold) AS SumOfunits_sold
FROM dim_product dp
INNER JOIN fact_sales fs
    ON dp.product_code = fs.product_code
GROUP BY
    dp.product_name
ORDER BY
    SUM(fe.units_sold);
```

Comment: oh thank you so much sir it work to me thank u so much...but can i get the first and last record at the same time ? i want to get maximum and minimum of Sum(fact_sales.units_sold)  how can i do ? please

Comment: @sandra One way would be to just union with a very similar query finding the minimum sum.

Comment: oh thank you so much sir for your help thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In MS-Access, the equivalent of `LIMIT` is `TOP` -- but `TOP` is really `TOP WITH TIES`.

So, you want to do something to ensure that only one row is returned when there are ties.  For that, just include a second sort key:

```
SELECT TOP (1) dim_product.product_name, Sum(fact_sales.units_sold) AS 
SumOfunits_sold
FROM dim_product INNER JOIN
     fact_sales 
     ON dim_product.product_code = fact_sales.product_code
GROUP BY dim_product.product_name
ORDER BY Sum(fact_sales.units_sold) DESC,
         dim_product.product_name;
```

This is guaranteed to return one row -- just as `LIMIT` would.

Comment: thank you so much for your help , its work for me correctly , thank u sir for this help